# Nuance of ひどい as cruel?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, grammar

> いくらなんでも、**あんまりひどい**。ひかりがあんなチョコレートででも組みあげたやうな三角標になるなんて。

http://contest.japias.jp/tqj2002/50133/story-old_03.html
I don't quite get how to translate  ひどい as cruel here, is there a nuance I'm not getting?

Comment: I’m confused — your question is assuming that ひどい = “cruel”, but where is this assumption coming from? Are you referencing an English translation of this work somewhere?

Comment: I assume that because that's the usual meaning of ひどい

Answer (score 2):

While `ひどい` can mean "cruel" when describing a person or behavior, it can also be used similar to the English "terrible" to describe bad or undesirable (but not necessarily cruel) situations or outcomes.

A common translation for `あんまりひどい` is "It was(is) [just] too much" though it doesn't quite work here.